# How can I see a list of members in a channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams

A few actions in Microsoft Teams will affect all of the members of a particular channel, and I would like to know which people would be reached (e.g. tagging a channel, scheduling an appointment in a channel).

How can I see the list of people in a channel that would be affected?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-who-s-on-a-team-or-in-a-channel-5c6be9be-9c45-4a0f-a1a0-f332b23cb6b7?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) seems out of date, since this option no longer shows up.

Comment: That option should be there for all non-guest users of the Team. The documentation is correct. Also, this is not a programming question?

Comment: I marked the programming-related answer as accepted. FWIW, it seems the UI-based answer is still a work in progress: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16911121-ability-to-see-who-is-in-a-channel

Comment: Ah, you're looking for a UI option for "Who is actively viewing this channel" not "Who are the members of this channel (which except for private channels is the same as the members of the team)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a Channel doesn't really contain members, the Team itself does (leaving out Private channels). In addition, recall that a Team is basically an Office 365 Group underneath. As a result, there are two ways to do what you need:

1) Either you can create a Bot, in which case it's easy to get this information, but it's a lot of work if you don't actually need a Bot

2) Alternatively, you can use the Microsoft Graph, in particular the [List Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) operation.

Comment: Not sure if you saw the comment on my question, but it seems like Microsoft supported this previously -- I cannot find any documentation about if/why the feature was removed. Regarding your first part: there must be some sort of mapping from channels to users, since specific people get notified when tagging the channel. Thanks for your two suggestions, I'll check them out!

Comment: I did see your comment, and that option is still available, but that's in the UI, I assumed you wanted a way to do it programmatically. Note that the option must be selected on the Team in the menu, not on the Channel (the screenshot is actually a tiny bit misleading - it looks like it's opening from the "Channel's" menu

Comment: I thought this was possible to see in the UI for public channels, but I only see it private channels. Thanks for your answer -- I'll mark it as accepted since it addresses the question programmatically.